# Seperate DNS settings for host and virtual machone

Tags: dns, vmware, opendns, virtualbox

For my host I want to use the ISP's standard DNS. However, I would like to test out for example Google's public DNS within a virtual machine, that is either Virtualbox or VMware workstation, without it affecting my hosts DNS settings. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the DNS servers within a virtual machine without changing your host machine. However it depends on your host network. For example, changing the DNS servers on your machine while at an internet café sometimes works and sometimes doesn't depending on their settings.

Comment: Is there a specific network setting I need to use like bridged or will work with the default NAT?

Comment: I've literally just tested my setup (OS X Mavericks host and Server 2003 guest on Virtual box). Mine is connected via bridged mode and it works perfectly. Again it totally depends on your internal setup (i.e the server/router that's dishing out the DNS settings - they might be forced on the client's). Give it a shot and if it doesn't work, post your settings.